# Error when installing pip3 install psycopg2: ld: 'library not found for -lssl'

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal, pip

When installing psycopg2 with pip3 I got the following error.

```
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Headers -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-81ywo8s1/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-81ywo8s1/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-r1isj9d_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Python/3.7m/include/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can provide more information of the log if needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Comment: Try `xcode-select --install`